# kendo-ui Window - How do you change the color of the title bar programatically?

Tags: kendo-ui, window

I have a page with two kendo ui Windows. Using javascript/html5 flavor.

How can I programatically change the color of the window title bar after it has been rendered on the page?

and also is there an event tied to the user clicking on the window?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

You can either change all Kendo Windows' CSS on the page, or get a specific instance, and change its titlebar CSS only:

```
kendoWindow.wrapper.find('.k-window-titlebar').css({
            color: 'red',
            'background-color': 'yellow' 
          });
```

... or

```
$('.k-widget.k-window .k-window-titlebar').css({
            color: 'red',
            'background-color': 'yellow' 
          });`
```

[Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/EhEtO)